# When invoking an async method that returns a list of objects, how do I make sure the result of the most "recent" request only is returned?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, syncfusion

I'm just dipping my toes into ASP.NET Core, and I'm not sure how to tackle this problem.

I'm using an AutoComplete control (Syncfusion) that, with every keystroke, sends a request to a Controller method, which in turn sends an API request.

The control itself doesn't seem relevant, but I'll include it anyway:

```
<ejs-autocomplete id="GiantBombAutocomplete" placeholder="Select a game" ignoreAccent="true" ignoreCase="true" filterType="Contains" autofill="true"
                filtering="GiantBombAutocomplete_Filtering" change="GiantBombAutocomplete_OnChange" select="GiantBombAutocomplete_OnSelect">
                    <e-data-manager adaptor="UrlAdaptor" url="/Home/GetGames/" crossDomain="false" onsubmit="Test"></e-data-manager>
                    <e-autocomplete-fields value="Name"></e-autocomplete-fields>
                </ejs-autocomplete>
```

The controller class, with GetGames being the relevant method:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> logger;
        private List<CancellationTokenSource>? cancellationTokenSources = null;

        public List<CancellationTokenSource> CancelationTokenSources
        {
            get
            {
                string? json = HttpContext.Session.GetString("CancellationTokens");

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(json))
                {
                    cancellationTokenSources = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CancellationTokenSource>>(json) ?? new List<CancellationTokenSource>();
                }
                else
                {
                    cancellationTokenSources = new List<CancellationTokenSource>();
                }

                return cancellationTokenSources;
            }
            set
            {
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("CancellationTokens", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
            }
        }

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index(string? name)
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Movies()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> GetGames([FromBody]Data dataManager, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
        {
            CancelationTokenSources.ForEach(x => x.Cancel());
            CancelationTokenSources = new List<CancellationTokenSource>() { new CancellationTokenSource() };

            var games = await GiantBombConnection.GetGames(dataManager.where[0].value, cancellationToken, CancelationTokenSources[0].Token);

            return Json(games);
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }

        public class Data
        {
            public int take { get; set; }
            public List<Wheres> where { get; set; }
        }

        public class Wheres
        {
            public string field { get; set; }
            public bool ignoreAccent { get; set; }

            public bool ignoreCase { get; set; }

            public bool isComplex { get; set; }

            public string value { get; set; }
            public string Operator { get; set; }

        }
    }
```

The API Connection:

```
public class GiantBombConnection
    {
        private const string BaseUrl = "https://www.giantbomb.com/api";
        private const string ApiKey = "api key";

        public static async Task<List<Game>> GetGames(string name, CancellationToken requestCancellationToken, CancellationToken getCancellationTokenSource)
        {
            var url = $"{BaseUrl}/games";
            var games = new List<Game>();
            var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

            query["api_key"] = ApiKey;
            query["format"] = "json";
            query["filter"] = $"name:{name}";

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, $"{url}?{query}");

                requestMessage.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "MvcMovie - App");

                var response = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
                var apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                try
                {
                    // Attempt to deserialise the reponse to the desired type, otherwise throw an expetion with the response from the api.
                    if (apiResponse != string.Empty)
                    {
                        var gamesResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GamesResponse>(apiResponse);

                        requestCancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                        getCancellationTokenSource.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                        return gamesResponse?.Results ?? new List<Game>();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new Exception();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception($"An error ocurred while calling the API. It responded with the following message: {response.StatusCode} {response.ReasonPhrase}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The issue I'm facing is as such: If I were to search, for example, 'Call of Duty', nearly every keystroke would cause a request. Because the first request (being the letter 'C') takes the longest, it more often than not gets returned last, causing the result set to be wrong.

Ideally, I'd like to have it so the result of the 'most recent' request is the one that gets returned, and the rest of the requests get cancelled.

I feel like one partial solution would be to only request the server once the user stops typing, but even then, a sufficiently long first request would still "overwrite" a second request, so this wouldn't necessarily solve the fundamental problem of having multiple concurrent requests and only wanting to take into account the result of the most recent request.

As you can see, I've tried to resolve the issue with a CancellationToken, but this doesn't seem to be working. When I call Cancel on the tokens, nothing happens. I assume I'm fundamentally misunderstanding how to persist a collection of CancellationTokens over a Session.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think this is an issue.  The control handles this automatically, and you aren't exactly sending completely different filters each keypress.   You could mitigate any chances by limiting the initial filter to requiring three or more characters using the minLength setting.  You could always set the control to client-filter by using a javascript array as your datasource and there would be no controller calls at all as the user types.  I'm not sure about syncfusion in particular but Telerik for example has a "client" filter mode that loads the whole dataset and filters locally.

Comment: @JohnLord Thanks for your reply. Minlength is definitely a good idea. Loading up the entire datasource isn't possible because it's definitely way too big. As to whether or not this is an issue, I'm definitely seeing the wrong result coming in last. For example, now with MinLength 3, when I look for something like "God of War", I get the the correct result list of all God of War games first, after which I get every game containing the word "God". I hope that's clear.

Comment: TL;DR but generally for autocomplete responses you include original prefix in the response and compare to the current value typed in the text box - if it matches - show all (or filtered down more if there are more letters typed - response for "ni"={"night", "nitro"} and currently typed in the textbox "nit" - fileter down to "nitro"), if prefix don't match just discard that response client side.

Comment: ok here's what you must do.  I checked our code in a similar situation.
When you make a request, set a variable to true, and set it to false when received.  Only allow new requests when the variable is true.  The initial lookups are evidently taking too long and allowing the users to change the filter before the next request.  If you prevent the next request until the last response comes in, you should not be able to get out of order.

Comment: @JohnLord Yup, that's the one! Thanks!

Comment: to clarify, i said that with wrong logic.  Only allow request when the boolean is false